# c compiler doesn't work ruby installation

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, rbenv

I am following [this](https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/2407918) guide install multiple ruby versions.

I have my C compiler working properly until I executed the below command few days back. I don't remember what was I trying to do.  Its just a guess that I did messed up with GCC few days back and this might be the issue. Correct me if I guessed wrong. As all this command says: remove -r gcc temperory files.

> NOTE: This error only shows when I am trying to install 1.8.7-p358 version. For 1.9.3-p125 it just works fine

```
❯ rm -r temp-gcc
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/ABOUT-NLS?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/aclocal.m4?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/add_gc_prefix.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/allchblk.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/alloc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/alpha_mach_dep.S?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/AmigaOS.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/backgraph.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/BCC_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/blacklst.c?
override rwxrwxr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/callprocs?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/ChangeLog?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/checksums.c?
override rwxrwxr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/configure?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/configure.ac?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/configure.host?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/cordbscs.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/cordprnt.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/cordtest.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/cordxtra.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/de.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/de_cmds.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/de_win.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/de_win.h?
override rwxrwxr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/de_win.ICO?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord/de_win.RC?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/cord?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/darwin_stop_world.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/dbg_mlc.c?
override rwxrwxr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/depcomp?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/digimars.mak?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/barrett_diagram?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/debugging.html?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/gc.man?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/gcdescr.html?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/gcinterface.html?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/leak.html?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.amiga?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.arm.cross?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.autoconf?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.changes?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.contributors?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.cords?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.darwin?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.DGUX386?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.dj?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.environment?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.ews4800?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.hp?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.linux?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.Mac?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.MacOSX?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.macros?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.OS2?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.rs6000?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.sgi?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.solaris2?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.uts?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/README.win32?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/scale.html?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/simple_example.html?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc/tree.html?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/doc?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/dyn_load.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/EMX_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/finalize.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gc.mak?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gc_cpp.cc?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gc_cpp.cpp?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gc_dlopen.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gcc_support.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gcj_mlc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/gcname.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/headers.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/hpux_test_and_clear.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/ia64_save_regs_in_stack.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/if_mach.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/if_not_there.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/cord.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/ec.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_alloc.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_allocator.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_amiga_redirects.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_backptr.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_config.h.in?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_config_macros.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_cpp.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_ext_config.h.in?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_gcj.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_inl.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_inline.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_local_alloc.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_mark.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_pthread_redirects.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/gc_typed.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/javaxfc.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/leak_detector.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/Makefile.am?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/Makefile.in?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/new_gc_alloc.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/cord_pos.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/darwin_semaphore.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/darwin_stop_world.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/dbg_mlc.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/gc_hdrs.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/gc_locks.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/gc_pmark.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/gc_priv.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/gcconfig.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/pthread_stop_world.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/pthread_support.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private/specific.h?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/private?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include/weakpointer.h?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/include?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Mac_files/dataend.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Mac_files/datastart.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Mac_files/MacOS_config.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Mac_files/MacOS_Test_config.h?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Mac_files?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/mach_dep.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/MacOS.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/MacProjects.sit.hqx?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Makefile.am?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Makefile.direct?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Makefile.dist?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Makefile.dj?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Makefile.DLLs?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/Makefile.in?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/malloc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/mallocx.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/mark.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/mark_rts.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/mips_sgi_mach_dep.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/mips_ultrix_mach_dep.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/misc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/new_hblk.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/NT_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/NT_STATIC_THREADS_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/NT_THREADS_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/obj_map.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/OS2_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/os_dep.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/pc_excludes?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/PCR-Makefile?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/pcr_interface.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/powerpc_darwin_mach_dep.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/pthread_stop_world.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/pthread_support.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/ptr_chck.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/real_malloc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/reclaim.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/rs6000_mach_dep.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/setjmp_t.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/SMakefile.amiga?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/sparc_mach_dep.S?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/sparc_netbsd_mach_dep.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/sparc_sunos4_mach_dep.s?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/specific.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/stubborn.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c/c.exp?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c/gctest.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c/leak_test.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c/middle.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c/thread_leak_test.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c/trace_test.c?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c++/test_cpp.cc?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.c++?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.lib/lib.exp?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.lib/staticrootslib.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.lib/staticrootstest.c?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/boehm-gc.lib?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/config/default.exp?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/config?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/lib/boehm-gc.exp?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/lib?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/Makefile.am?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite/Makefile.in?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/testsuite?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/threadlibs.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/threads.mk.in?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/typd_mlc.c?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/version.h?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/WCC_MAKEFILE?
override rw-rw-r--  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc/win32_threads.c?
override rwxr-xr-x  1000/1000 for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/boehm-gc?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/fixincludes/Makefile?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/fixincludes/mkheaders?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/fixincludes/mkheaders.almost?
rm: temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/fixincludes: Directory not empty
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/libiberty/Makefile?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/libiberty/testsuite/Makefile?
rm: temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/libiberty/testsuite: Directory not empty
rm: temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/libiberty: Directory not empty
rm: temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/build-x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0: Directory not empty
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/ada/gcc-interface/Makefile?
rm: temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/ada/gcc-interface: Directory not empty
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/ada/Makefile?
rm: temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/ada: Directory not empty
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/as?
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/collect-ld?
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/collect2?
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cpp?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cppbuiltin.o?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cppdefault.o?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cs-bconfig.h?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cs-config.h?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cs-tconfig.h?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cs-tm.h?
override rw-r--r--  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/cs-tm_p.h?
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/g++?
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/gcc-ar?
override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for temp-gcc/gcc-4.7.2/build/gcc/gcc-nm? ^C
```

when I try to **install** *ruby1.8.7-p358* using **rbenv**

Checking to see if C compiler is working...no

```
❯ rbenv install 1.8.7-p358
Downloading ruby-1.8.7-p358.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.7-p358.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-1.8.7-p358...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.3 using ruby-build 20160228)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/5n/ghyfb6n9387_h2w5ycg9pd980000gn/T/ruby-build.20160319044654.46596
Results logged to /var/folders/5n/ghyfb6n9387_h2w5ycg9pd980000gn/T/ruby-build.20160319044654.46596.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/5n/ghyfb6n9387_h2w5ycg9pd980000gn/T/ruby-build.20160319044654.46596/ruby-1.8.7-p358 /var/folders/5n/ghyfb6n9387_h2w5ycg9pd980000gn/T/ruby-build.20160319044654.46596 ~/.rbenv
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-readline-dir
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin15.3.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin15.3.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin15.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/5n/ghyfb6n9387_h2w5ycg9pd980000gn/T/ruby-build.20160319044654.46596/ruby-1.8.7-p358':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

Maybe you have some missing packages which can be used to compile C program.
Try running these commands on your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

For OSX

```
brew uninstall gcc46
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Comment: I am using OSX see the tag